# How to Get the scheduledID of a scheduled job when sending a message to ActiveMQ

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

I want to be able to delete any(some) scheduled messages programmatically from ActiveMQ, but for that, I need a scheduled job ID. Is there any way to get this ID, something like a response when I send a scheduled message to the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the scheduled jobs can only be queried using the Job Scheduler JMX [Mbean](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/jmx/JobSchedulerView.html) or via the messaging based management support which has been written about [here](http://timbish.blogspot.com/2010/10/enhanced-jms-scheduler-in-activemq.html).